# Parse multidimensional JSON array without key

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to display the different provinces including their shops, which are inside a multidimensional array, on a webpage, but I can't manage to display the nested arrays that lack a key.

I've tried giving the array a key, tried "parse.Land.0", "parse.Land.i" and "parse.Land[0]" to get the information, but none of it seems to work. In the case of "parse.Land[0]", it would return the first letter of the country's name instead of the first result in the nested array. We've also tried to construct the array in several different ways, but none of it worked.

PHP Code to get the information from a database:

```php
$Land = ['Land' => $_GET['data']];

$Nederland = array("Groningen", "Friesland", "Drenthe", "Overijssel", "Flevoland", "Gelderland", "Utrecht", "Noord-Holland", "Zuid-Holland", "Zeeland", "Noord-Brabant", "Limburg");
$Andere = array("Etc", "Etcetera");
switch ($_GET['data']) {
    case "Nederland":
        $country = $Nederland;
        $fieldID = 5;
        break;
    case "Andere":
        $country = $Andere;
        $fieldID = 18;
        break; 
}
    foreach($country as $data) {
        $locationData = [];
        $getProvince= $_db->prepare("SELECT user_id, value FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = ".$fieldID." AND value = '".$data."'");
        $getProvince->execute();

        $displayProvince = $getProvince->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($displayProvince as $dataProvince) {
           $getName= $_db->prepare("SELECT value FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 1 AND user_id = ".$dataProvince['user_id']);
           $getName->execute();
           $displayName = $getName->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           foreach($displayName as $dataName) {
               $locationData[] = ['Info' => $dataName['value']];
           }
        }
        $Land[] = [$data => $locationData];
    }

echo json_encode($Land);
```

PHP code results to this JSON array:

```
{"Land":"Nederland","0":{"Groningen":[{"Info":""},{"Info":""}]},"1":{"Friesland":[]},"2":{"Drenthe":[]},"3":{"Overijssel":[]},"4":{"Flevoland":[]},"5":{"Gelderland":[]},"6":{"Utrecht":[]},"7":{"Noord-Holland":[{"Info":"Placeholder"},{"Info":"Test"},{"Info":"Anna Paulowna"},{"Info":"Den Helder"}]},"8":{"Zuid-Holland":[{"Info":"zuidholland"},{"Info":"zuidholland2"}]},"9":{"Zeeland":[{"Info":"Middelburg"}]},"10":{"Noord-Brabant":[]},"11":{"Limburg":[]}}
```

Ajax to display the information on a webpage:

```
function getData(land) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/GetData.php',
            data: {data: land},
            success: function (data) {

                var parse = JSON.parse(data);
                var object = Object.keys(parse).length;
                var element = document.getElementById('content');
                for (var i = 0; i < object; i++) {
                    var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    mainDiv.setAttribute('class', 'accordion_holder');
                    element.appendChild(mainDiv);
                    var accordion = document.createElement('button');
                    accordion.setAttribute('class', 'accordion');
                    mainDiv.appendChild(accordion);
                    var icon = document.createElement('i');
                    icon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-angle-right');
                    accordion.appendChild(icon);
                    accordion.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', parse.Land);
                }
                console.log(parse);
            }
        });

    var element = document.getElementById(land);

    element.classList.add('active');

    }
```

I want to be able to get the value of the inner array with the key "Info".
Instead I either get an error saying that getData() is undefined, or just the first letter of the country. I expected to be able to do something along the lines of "parse.Land.7.Noord-Holland.Info" and for it to return the value "Placeholder".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `parse[0]` looks like it

Comment: That returns [object Object], it does contain the values that I want. But I don't know how to retrieve them. How do I make it display the provinces only?

Comment: `parse[0]` will compute to `{"Groningen":[{"Info":""},{"Info":""}]}` when you print this it will be [object Object], if you need the first element then `Object.keys(parse[0])[0]` should give you Groningen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse[0]` will compute to

> {"Groningen":[{"Info":""},{"Info":""}]}

when you print this it will be `[object Object]`, if you need the first element then

`Object.keys(parse[0])[0]`

should give you **Groningen**

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use the following:

```
Object.keys(parse[i])[0])
```

To loop through all results.